# Is setting a pointer to zero equivalent to setting it to NULL?

Tags: c++, c

I searched in the web but couldn't find a reliable answer.
And what would

```
someclass* ptr = 1;
char* charptr = 2;
```

or assigning them to any other integer mean?

What happens if I don't initialize pointers (for native data pointers as well as class pointers) before using them?

Comment: I replaced "equating" with "assigning"; since the latter is the name of the operation that the `=` symbol represents. You assign values to variables.

Comment: @unwind: Ironically, in the OP's code sample there are no assignments, only initializations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in C++ NULL is defined to be 0. Setting a pointer to some other small integer value would mean it pointed to a -- likely illegal -- portion of the computer's memory (but it wouldn't be considered a NULL pointer).

If you don't initialize a global pointer it will be set to zero (NULL) for you just before the program starts. If you don't initialize pointer variables declared on the stack (i.e. as within functions or methods) they will have garbage in them. Likewise, the contents of any dynamically allocated pointer or any contained in an object as a data member also will have no predefined value. Some compilers have extensions that allow requests for dynamically allocated memory to be initially zeroed, like C's `calloc()` function does for raw memory.

Comment: Thanks. 
So the only case where an uninitialized pointer will be set to NULL by the compiler automatically, is for global pointers?

Comment: "in C++ NULL is defined to be 0", or `0L`, `false`. And now in C++11, `std::nullptr`. Since you always have a conversion _to_ a pointer type, there's some flexibility in what you can convert _from_.

Comment: @ontherocks: No, `static` pointers are another case. Pointers in classes should be zero-initialized by your constructor (if not assigned a definite value).

Comment: @MSalters. Thanks. You meant "Pointers _to_ classes", right?   If the only constructor present is the default one, then <code>myclass * ptr;</code> would be NULL?

Comment: Using `calloc` does not initialize any pointers in the allocated block to `NULL` -- rather, it initializes them to the value represented by an all-zeros pattern, which may be different from `NULL` (for example, I have an embedded system on which `NULL` is represented by `0x20000000`, and the compiler generates an XOR instruction for pointer <-> integer conversions).

Comment: @ontherocks: No, I specifically meant pointers _in_ classes, i.e. as data members of classes. For your example, `myclass * ptr` the stated rules apply: it's NULL if and only if it's a global or `static`, since there's no initializer.

Comment: @ontherocks: Well, not exactly. They don't have to be global to be set to zero, just statically allocated. For example a variable declared `static` and defined in a compilation unit, or one in a function/method will also be, although neither are global.

Comment: @MSalters @martineau: Thanks. One more.  Is `char mychar = 0;` equivalent to `char * mychar = NULL;`?

Comment: @ontherocks: No, not the same. The first declares a `char` variable capable of holding one character and initialized with the character value `\x00`. The second declares a variable which is a pointer to one or more `char`s (an array of them) and sets its initial value to `NULL` (i.e. zero).

Comment: @ontherocks: The first declares a `char`, while the second declares a `char *`. How can they possibly be equivalent?

Comment: @AndreyT: Of what significance is the actual or physical value of a null pointer?

Comment: @AndreyT: I never mentioned what portion of memory a NULL pointer would point to, only the likely interpretation of pointers somehow assigned (other) small integer values.

Comment: @martineau: OK. In that case I take my words back. I misunderstood what you intended to say said and I sincerely apologize for that.

Comment: @martineau: So `char mychar = <some integer>`, where the integer is not enclosed in single quotes, means assigning mychar the corresponding character value of the integer. Right?

Comment: @ontherocks: Actually it's assigning an integer value to a char variable. The `char` data type is actually a small (signed or unsigned) integer type of at least 8-bits. So `char ch = '\n'` is the same as `char ch = 10` because the `ord('\n') == 10`.

Answer (score 3):

Setting a pointer to `0` is equivalent to setting it to `NULL`. However, this is only true for a *constant expression* `0`, i.e. for compile-time zero value. Trying to set a pointer to a run-time zero value is not guaranteed to produce a null pointer

```
int *pi = 0; // Initializes a null pointer
char *pc = 2 - 2; // Initializes a null pointer
short *ps = sizeof *pc - 1; // Initializes a null pointer

int x = 0;
double *pd = (double *) x; 
// Implementation-defined, not guaranteed to produce a null pointer
```

You can explore the matter in greater detail [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/null/)

To answer the second part of your question:

It is illegal to assign any other integer (besides literal/constant 0) to a pointer. Neither of your initializations (or assignments) will compile. It is illegal in both C and C++, although C compilers are historically more permitting in this regard, responding with a warning instead of refusing to compile the code.

Also, in C++ language there's no difference of how pointers to class types are treated. Pointer to class types are still considered scalar types and behave in this regard the same way as any pointer to a fundamental type does.

Comment: >It is illegal to assign any other integer (besides literal/constant 0) to a pointer.  
That is not true anymore: You are allowed to assign any arbitrary value.
https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1438.html